# How can I set iterm2 theme like the secure-crt?

Tags: iterm2, secure-crt

I have been using `securecrt` for a long time, now I switch to use `iterm2`, but I cannot set a same color theme in `securecrt` (session options/Terminal/Emulation, set Terminal to Linux).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I got it, just set the `ansi color` same with `securecrt`.